# How to Connect to Okta LDAP?

Tags: php, ldap, okta, idp

So, I have an LDAP directory with Okta set up. I am having trouble connecting to it using PHP. Here's my code:

```
$domain = 'phishingboxdecember15thaccount.ldap.okta.com';
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$ldapconfig['host'] = '44.234.52.17';  // I got this by pinging the domain. I guess that's correct?
$ldapconfig['port'] = 636;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=phishingboxdecember15thaccount,dc=okta,dc=com';

$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$dn="ou=users,".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
$bind=ldap_bind($ds, $username .'@' .$domain, $password);
print_r($bind);
$isITuser = ldap_search($bind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=' . $username. '))');
if ($isITuser) {
    echo("Login correct");
} else {
    echo("Login incorrect");
}
```

Yet this never works. Always get "Login incorrect", and I am certain that I'm using the correct password (although, I'm not sure about the username part - I just use the username I enter to login to my Okta admin account, I'm assuming that's correct?).

Do you have any ideas/tips on how I can connect to the Okta LDAP using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The settings you need are in the documentation [here](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/LDAP-interface-connection-settings.htm). The one that jumps out to me is the host should be of the form <org_subdomain>.ldap.okta.com as you have in the domain variable.

I think your search will need to be tweaked to:`ldap_search($bind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=' . $username. '))');` but that won't be stopping your login.